# Sqlite select previous/next row from composite primary keys

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm using sqlite3. Say if I have a table, t, and three fields, id, A, B and C, where id is the primary key.

To select the previous row based on the order of the id, I do:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE ? < id ORDER BY id desc limit 1
```

and for next row, I do:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE ? > id ORDER BY id ASC limit 1
```

But what if I have composite primary keys and I want to get the previous/next row?

I.e. what if my fields are id1, id2, id3, A, B, C and id1, id2 and id3 are my composite primary keys.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Same idea but the comparison logic is more cumbersome:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE (id1 < ?) OR
      (id1 = ? AND id2 < ?) OR
      (id1 = ? AND id2 = ? AND id3 < ?)
ORDER BY id1, id2, id3 ASC 
LIMIT 1;
```

You can also use tuple comparisons:

```
WHERE(id1, id2, id3) <(?, ?, ?)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to include all the components of the composite key on the `ORDER BY`

So the statements become.

`SELECT * FROM t WHERE ? < id ORDER BY id DESC, letter DESC limit 1`

and

`SELECT * FROM t WHERE ? > id ORDER BY id ASC, letter ASC limit 1`

Note that you will have to pay attention to which order you want the separate components to be in.